# Large $x$ behavior of a Taylor series with infinite radius of convergence

Tags: asymptotics

Given a Taylor series expression of a function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, with an infinite radius of convergence, are there any basic/standard techniques for understanding the asymptotic behavior of the function as $x\to\infty$? How is the asymptotic behavior of some of the more famous functions, e.g. Bessel functions, Hypergeometric functions, etc. determined?

Comment: A lot use their equivalent integral formulations and then use special techniques to compute approximations. Just check the wiki page on Bessel functions and you'll see it.

Comment: There are wildly different functions with Taylor series with infinite convergence radius. For example, $\;e^x, \sin x, \cos x, 1\;$ All have infinite radius of convergence and they all behave differently when $\;x\to\infty\;$ , so I don't think much can be said...

Comment: If you have the $a_n$ in any sort of recursive form, convert to a differential equation and then work with that.

Comment: The examples I'm familiar with involve rewriting the function as an integral and applying some form of Laplace's method, and I'd guess the Bessel functions can be done this way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: See a possible method [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#iii). You can also look up Hayman's method, the Harris-Schoenfeld method, Grosswald's method and Wayman's method.